# R fonts render differently in different PDF viewers

Tags: r, plot, graphics, fonts

I am saving figures in R like so:

```
pdf('test.pdf', family='Palatino')
plot(1) 
dev.off()
```

The output looks like this in SumatraPDF:

[image: SumatraPDF]

but like this in Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

Why do they look so different, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postscript()` and `pdf()` devices in R do not embed any fonts, c.f. `?postscript`. So the PDF viewer has to substitute another font. And in this case both of them use fonts that do not look like Palatino. It should look more like this:

[image]

Alternatives:

- `cairo_pdf` as suggested by [SirSaleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2454690/sirsaleh)
- Post-processing with the `embedFonts()` function:

  ```
  pdf('test.pdf', family='Palatino')
  plot(1) 
  dev.off() 
  embedFonts("test.pdf", outfile = "test2.pdf")
  ```

This requires that you have a suitable font installed somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this works for you too or not. But I had same problem with `pdf` function but after using same commands with `cairo_pdf` my problem solved:

```
cairo_pdf('test.pdf', family='Palatino')
plot(1) 
dev.off()
```